# bundler: command not found: jekyll

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, jekyll

I have a project for uni where we need to build upon an existing project.
To view it locally I need to build it with Jekyll. I have never worked with it and am generally not very experienced with coding. To build the website we are supposed to use

```
bundle exec jekyll build -d public
```

Now this gives me the error

```
bundler: command not found: jekyll
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

When I check my ruby version it says

```
ruby 3.1.0p0 (2021-12-25 revision fb4df44d16) [x86_64-darwin20]
```

Also tried some PATH redirecting so which ruby gives me

```
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
```

the gems are under

```
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/gem
```

I'm pretty lost now and not sure what to do.
I'm working on a Mac btw :)
Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you tried to run `bundle install` as indicated in the error message? What happened?

Comment: it installs it. But still gives the error message. My guess is it is in a wrong location but changing both paths to the above didn't help either

Comment: Did you install Ruby or using what was already preloaded on your machine? If manually, what steps did you take?

Comment: I have a different ruby installed. Ruby 3.1 something. I then changed the PATH to the above one, after someone’s suggestion in another thread (not mine)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the Jekyll gem installed?

```
gem install jekyll
```